# Section title appearing twice in header

Tags: beamer, header-footer

With the following code the Section Title 
"Section" appears twice in the header -- once for the first page, once for the other three pages. It seems to me that this is a bug.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\section{Section}
Text 1\pause\\
Text 2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Text 3\pause\\
Text 4
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use the section inside of a frame, always outsides

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but you should not use \\ for line  breaks, leave an empty line instead